# "Discord is not refined"

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am very new to coding and I tried coding my own discord bot and I got the "discord is not refined" in command prompt. I am currently just trying to turn on the bot to see if it works, anyways here  is the code

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();



client.once('ready'),  () => {
    console.log('HelloMyFriend is online!');
};



client.login('<token>');

stack trace 
events.js:131
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
←[90m    at checkListener (events.js:131:11)←[39m
←[90m    at Client.once (events.js:496:3)←[39m
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jamie\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:7:8)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'←[39m
 }
```

Comment: Can you share a full stacktrace?

Comment: @Mureinik i have just shared the stacktrace, I apologise for replying so late

Comment: Avoid sharing your token next time, it's essentially your bot's login password. If you haven't already regenerate it

Comment: If you're new to programming I highly suggest you first learn the basics of JavaScript and NodeJS. Most users who don't know a lick of programming and try to make a Discord bot get stressed on the simplest of things and end up quiting because tutorials do not cover what they want.

Answer (score 0):

The first event `on ready` is wrong. You shouldn't be closing the parentheses after the `'ready'`.
You should also use `on` instead of `once`.

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('HelloMyFriend is online!');
});
```

Comment: `client.once("ready", ...` is fine as it only fires a single time.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this error you can replace your `ready` event with the following:

```py
client.once('ready', () => {
console.log('HelloMyFriend is online!'); 
});
```

I would also recommend an `.env` file to protect the token of the bot. Once it becomes public, it should be generated again in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) to prevent possible hijacking of the bot.

Comment: This seems to be the same as [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67617397/14267427). Therefore it is a duplicate.

Comment: oh. My bad i did not see the answer below I'm a new user here.